# Unlock Package error: Invalid Type

Tags: apex, managed-package, unlocked-package

I install a manage package on my scratch org first, found few issues so I uninstalled and uploaded the same metadata as unlock package to test the code, but when I update any apex class getting an error on the custom setting

> Invalid Type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to the salesforce recovery plan, we need to wait for 48 hours to permanently delete all components in this package from the org.

[Best practices when uninstalling an app or package](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000319882&type=1)